# MySQL select distinct or group by optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I am having a problem getting unique results from a query.  The Detail table has 800K rows and the Matrix table has 988K rows.  There are indexes but either I don't have the correct indexes set up or they can't be used with the query. Explain says the there are no possible keys for the Detail table.  Matrix shows possible keys but the key value is NULL and Extra says:

```
Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  Detail.Geocode AS Geocode,
  Detail.Taxtype AS Taxtype,
  Detail.TaxCat AS TaxCat,
  Detail.TaxAuthId AS TaxAuthId,
  Detail.TaxRate AS TaxRate,
  Detail.Fee AS Fee,
  Matrix.`Group` AS `Group`,
  Matrix.Item AS Item,
  Matrix.Customer AS Customer
FROM Detail
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Matrix
    ON Detail.Taxtype = Matrix.TaxType
    AND Detail.TaxCat = Matrix.TaxCat
    AND Detail.Geocode = Matrix.Geocode
    OR Matrix.Geocode = CONCAT(SUBSTR(Detail.Geocode, 1, 4), '00000000')
    AND Matrix.TaxAuthId = Detail.TaxAuthId
    OR ISNULL(Matrix.TaxAuthId)
```

Executing the query above completes OK but results in tons of duplicates.  I expected this given the data that I am working with.

I have tried using DISTINCT and GROUP BY but it never completes.

E.g

```
GROUP BY Detail.Geocode,
         Detail.Taxtype,
         Detail.TaxCat,
         Detail.TaxAuthId,
         Detail.TaxRate,
         Detail.Fee,
         Matrix.`Group`,
         Matrix.Item,
         Matrix.Customer
```

I have seen some examples where DISTINCT is placed inside the join but I have not been able to figure out how to do that properly with my query.

Comment: Your `ON` clause just can't be optimized.  I would suggest asking another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic that you want to achieve.

Comment: OR's w/o proper ()'s could be your problem.  use ()'s to denote how the ORs are to operate with the ANDs.  Do you have 3 separate conditions here? or less/more?  It really seems odd to check for matrix.taxauthID is null when matrix is on the right side of a left join especially without any other matching criteria.

Comment: I saw you've got ON... AND AND AND OR AND OR.. to me this seems like an odd way to put them. I would keep the ORS together at the end, or group them in brackets if that's what you are trying to do

Comment: The problem was with the ().

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with ().  Thanks xQbert!

```
SELECT
  Detail.Geocode AS Geocode,
  Detail.Taxtype AS Taxtype,
  Detail.TaxCat AS TaxCat,
  Detail.TaxAuthId AS TaxAuthId,
  Detail.TaxRate AS TaxRate,
  Detail.Fee AS Fee,
  Matrix.`Group` AS `Group`,
  Matrix.Item AS Item,
  Matrix.Customer AS Customer
FROM Detail
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Matrix
    ON Detail.Taxtype = Matrix.TaxType
    AND Detail.TaxCat = Matrix.TaxCat
    AND (Detail.Geocode = Matrix.Geocode
    OR Matrix.Geocode = CONCAT(SUBSTR(Detail.Geocode, 1, 4), '00000000'))
    AND (Matrix.TaxAuthId = Detail.TaxAuthId
    OR ISNULL(Matrix.TaxAuthId))
```